# Uploading files to Meteor via DDP

Tags: python, file-upload, meteor, ddp

I am working on a project where I need to upload a files from a client (which is running a python script) to my Meteor app where the audio file will be processed and send a response back to the client. Once the client receives the response it will upload another file which starts the whole process over again.

I have been using [github.com/foxdog-studios/pyddp](https://github.com/foxdog-studios/pyddp) to call various methods via DDP but can't figure out the best way to transfer a file from the client to Meteor. Any help on the proper way to upload files to Meteor would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and talking to several other Meteor developers it looks like DDP is not a good solution for files uploading. Apparently when CollectionsFS was first being developed they tried using DDP but switched over to a REST API do to speed and reliability issues. So in short their is not a good way to upload files via DDP.

To solve my problem I ended up creating a rest api and using CollectionsFS. I found this [tutorial](http://www.codetutorial.io/meteor-server-file-upload/) to be extremely helpful!